# SPARQL entity lists inside select queries

Tags: sparql

In the following DBpedia query, is there a way to consolidate the UNIONs into a single pattern?

```
PREFIX prop: <http://resedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX res: <http://resedia.org/resource/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?language ?label 
WHERE { 
  {res:Spain prop:language ?language} 
    UNION
  {res:France prop:language ?language}
    UNION
  {res:Italy prop:language ?language}
  ?language rdfs:label ?label .
  FILTER langMatches(lang(?label), "en") 
}
```

The [SPARQL spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#collections) mentions something about RDF collections but I don't really understand what it's describing. It seemed like the following syntax should work, but it didn't.

```
PREFIX prop: <http://resedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX res: <http://resedia.org/resource/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?language ?label 
WHERE { 
  (res:Spain res:France res:Italy) prop:language ?language
  ?language rdfs:label ?label .
  FILTER langMatches(lang(?label), "en") 
}
```

Is there a way to define a list (or "multiset", or "bag") of URIs like this inside a SELECT query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: no.

```
(res:Spain res:France res:Italy) prop:language ?language
```

means 'match where a list containing Spain, France and Italy has a language', i.e. the list itself has a language.

You could do:

```
?country prop:language ?language . ?language rdfs:label ?label . 
FILTER ( ?country == res:Spain || ?country == res:France || ?country == res:Italy )
```

which is shorter, but may be slower.

(I had a feeling SPARQL 1.1 had an 'IN' feature, but I don't see it in the drafts)

Comment: That's unfortunate, maybe something like this will be added in later versions. Thanks for the clarification and suggestion. On a related note, is there a way to assign a single URI to a query variable and use that variable elsewhere in the query?

Comment: In standard SPARQL 1.0, no, although you can prebind variables in some systems.

In SPARQL 1.1 and some systems, yes. See e.g. http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/925/927#927. SELECT with a sub SELECT will definitely work in SPARQL 1.1. LET might get in.

Comment: Oh, and of course { ... FILTER ( ?var = <uri> ) } has same effect.

Comment: There is `IN` in SPARQL 1.1: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-in

Answer (score 7):

In SPARQL 1.1 you can do

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?language ?label 
WHERE {
  ?country prop:language ?language .
  ?language rdfs:label ?label .
  VALUES ?country { res:Spain res:France res:Italy }
  FILTER langMatches(lang(?label), "en") 
}
```